# Swapping a running jar at runtime

Tags: java, file, plugins, jar, locking

I am building an update system in which I need to be able to replace a referenced jar of a running application jar at runtime. However, I am running into file locking issues on Windows when trying to perform file utility functions on the jar such as 'setLastModified'.

After some googling I found this snippet...

> What I found in my research is that
>   the standard ClassLoader
>   implementation *never* closes a jar
>   file once it has been opened. It also
>   only loads resources from the jar file
>   as needed. So at any particular time,
>   there may be Classes in the jar file
>   that have not been loaded into memory.
>   Obviously, if you delete the jar file
>   out from under the ClassLoader, and it
>   tries to find a resource in the
>   missing file, you're going to get an
>   IOException at the very least.

Does anyone have any references to information on doing this, or working around this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to re-invent the wheel?  OSGi has hot deployment already.  Have a look and see if you could use that instead.

Comment: OSGi sound like overwhelming for most requirements, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2463978/320594

Comment: After re-reading it seems you want to keep your application running but with the new jars... so OSGi really looks like a good solution :), for example Eclipse allows for that (plugins reload while running) and uses OSGi for that (as long as I know).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a lot of solutions for classes/lib hot-swapping :

- [Hotswap for ant](https://hotswap.dev.java.net/)
- [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/)
- [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage)

It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: OSGi is huge and JRebel is only for development since it requires an expensive license (free for OSS projects). Not sure about Hotswap for ant

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing is [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)

Please have a look at the 'See also' section of the mentioned artice for concrete products.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any good way to deal with this. Creating a custom classloader might be an option, although I don't like that idea..

We worked around it by running an updater from a separate jar before launching the main application. This works well enough, but obviously, you can only update the jar when the application is launched.