# How to dynamically update (hot swap) jars in a web-app?

Tags: java, tomcat, cloud-foundry, hotswap, web-inf

I have a webapp in a war archive which is deployed on cloudfoundry.
One of the libraries ("`somelib.jar`") used by the app is made by another developer.

I would like a way for him to upload several different versions of `somelib.jar` and test the behaviour of the app.
I have managed to get the jar uploaded to `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the deployment. I have also managed to unpack the jar into `WEB-INF/classes`. However, I have not managed to get the new version of the jar to be used. I tried various hacks such as those described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621505/swapping-a-running-jar-at-runtime) without any luck.

Everytime, the classes/jars that get loaded the first time get used after that, even if we replace the actual `.class` or `.jar` file in the above directories.

Is there any easy way to achieve what I want?

Note: Since I dont have control of Tomcat (where it runs), I cannot configure Tomcat or make any changes to the server. I just have control on my war file, *so everything needs to be done programmatically*.

EDIT: the reason I want this is to reduce our testing time. Currently someone gives me a new version of `somelib.jar`, I repackage it into my application, upload to CF, send him a notification, then he tests the behavior of the new jar. What I would have preferred is that he upload his jar directly to CF and do the testing whenever he has a new version without the unnecessary intermediate delay.

Comment: you can drop a completely new war file, because the webapp directory is usually doing hot deploy unless that configuration is turned off in tomcat. That only allows you to have one version running at once but it does 'hot deploy' without a restart. There are problems with this and nobody would seriously consider doing this in a production environment.

Comment: I can't believe there is not a simple solution to this. With the advent of PaaS, it is more and more likely that customers will not like to be bothered or be in control of the server configuration.

Comment: You're suffering from a process problem, not a technology problem. If you want a simple solution, give each team member a test environment and the ability to build their own deployable WAR.

Comment: I managed to get it to work using standard java reflection API. I will put the solution here when I get some time. If anyone is interested, please comment here.

Answer (score 2):

In tomcat 7, you can version your WAR file and the new versions will gradually kick in.

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/05/31/parallel-deployment-tomcat-7

Comment: Like I said, I am running the app on cloudfoundry and I dont have control or any say on the configuration or the version of Tomcat they use.

Comment: As Ali said above, you can have control over the Tomcat version and config. Along with his link, this one has some good info:http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/

Comment: Also, this doesn't help you right now, but Cloud Foundry is implementing buildpacks to replace the existing method of staging apps. Modifying an existing buildpack will be an easy way to customize how apps are staged and configured. Watch for details here: http://cloudfoundry.github.com/docs/roadmap.html and here: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!forum/vcap-dev

Answer (score 2):

> Everytime, the classes/jars that get loaded the first time get used after that, even if we replace the actual .class or .jar file in the above directories

That's the way that normal Tomcat (Java EE) [classloading](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) works. Your classes are loaded when first deployed, and any changes will be ignored (JSPs are managed slightly differently, but only in a development environment).

You should be able to solve this problem by using the Equinox [OSGi bridge servlet](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php). I haven't done this myself, but [here's](http://techdistrict.kirkk.com/2009/02/16/embedding-osgi-in-tomcat/) a writeup by a person that I respect.

Comment: is is possible to configure different classloader for development environment?

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to control the application server yourself, you would need to deploy a standalone app into Cloud Foundry.

This blog should help you out with that:

http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/11/running-standalone-web-applications-on-cloud-foundry/

This way you can custom configure your tomcat.